# Seam unexpected createInstance call

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, seam, seam2

I have a xhtml page, in which i'm trying to open a dialog and set/change some values. Page is normally backed by MemberInformationService, in this page's page.xml, i call a wire function to set some values into MemberLogHome's instance. Everything goes perfect. When i press the commandButton to open dialog, I can see that MemberLogHome's instance is setted correctly, ( I can see the values i set on the dialog) but at the same time, there is an unexpected createInstance call which later continues with a setInstance that makes MemberLogHome's instance values null. Because of this when i submit my dialog i get errors. I couldnt find what makes the unexpected call. Also this call is executed whenever i open a dialog. I'm using Seam 2.3 and primefaces 3.5

Classes are pretty big i'm writing just the parts i think relevant

Inside of Xhtml:

```
<p:menuitem value="#{messages.overallChange}"
                                onclick="dlg2.show()" />

<p:dialog header="#{messages.overallChange}" widgetVar="dlg2"
        modal="true" resizable="true" appendToBody="true">
<h:form>
<p:panelGrid columns="1">
                        <s:decorate template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                            <ui:define name="label">#{messages.memberId}</ui:define>
                            <p:inputText
                                value="#{memberLogHome.instance.memberByNewMemberId.id}" />
                        </s:decorate>
....
<h:commandButton value="#{messages.submit}"
                action="#{memberInformationService.saveOverallChange}"
                oncomplete="dlg2.hide();" />
</h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Inside of MemberInformationService

```
@Name("memberInformationService")
@Scope(ScopeType.PAGE)
public class MemberInformationService {
@In(create = true)
MemberLogHome memberLogHome;
    ...
public void wire() {
...
fillMemberLog();
}
public void fillMemberLog(){

memberLogHome.clearInstance();
memberLogHome.setInstance(new MemberLog());

memberLogHome.getInstance().setBranchByNewBranchId(trustMemberHome.getInstance().getBranch());
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `public void wire()` is called with an `<action />` tag in your page.xml, make sure its `on-postback` attribute is set to `false`, otherwise it will be called again on any postback, including the form submit, executing the first two lines of `fillMemberLog()` and clearing the values in the instance.